# How to set the domain name and subdomain name without port number for same ip address?

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I want to set
172.01.03.04:8000 to example.com
and
172.01.03.04:9000 to subdomain.example.com

## Ubuntu_18.04

## Nginx

## Laravel 5.5

## Need_Help

Advanced Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you setup nginx by default http then you will get it port 80 or setup with ssl like https then it will set port 443. But if you set up port manually then you have to hit with external port in browser. your problem seems like you are using external port. so 
1. you may use reverse proxy to use port 8000 but in backend port should be by 80/443 
2. you can use soft firewall if your os have.

Comment: SSL certificate is not being added. I have used reverse proxy but that did not work.

Comment: reverse proxy might not properly set. you may see these links before applying: 
https://www.keycdn.com/support/nginx-reverse-proxy
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/
https://dev.to/shameemreza/accelerate-your-website-with-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-cache-a9o
https://serverfault.com/questions/242052/gotchas-for-reverse-proxy-setups
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/issues-with-a-reverse-proxy